# How properly perform passing operation result to View

Tags: coding-style, mvc

I'm developing web site on self made MVC engine.
I have *actionController* that handles operations like *register*, *login*, *post submit* and etc. *actionController* receives operation name and parameters.
Of course it mast handle errors such *user with same nick already exists* or *password is to short* about which action handler have to notify user. The question is which is the best way to organize errors, such that View could easily get localized user notification message.

I see two ways

First one:
define error constants like

```
ERR_NICK_BUSY = '1'
ERR_NICK_INVALID = '2'
...
```

and localization map

```
local[ERR_NICK_BUSY] = 'User with the same nick already registered'
local[ERR_NICK_INVALID ] = 'Nick, you entered is invalid'
...
```

And second one:
define abstract constants like

```
ERR_FIELD_BUSY = '1'
ERR_FIELD_INVALID = '2'
...
```

and pass them with field name. In this case localization looks like

```
local['nick_'+ERR_FIELD_BUSY] = 'User with the same nick already registered'
...
```

I don't like both this methods. Can you advise something else?

Answer (score 1):

How about extending the Exception class and throwing your own exceptions.

You could have a yml file with the error code, type, default message.

```
try {

/* some code */

} catch(MyException $e) {

    echo $e->getError(2)['message'];    

}

class MyException extends Exception{


function getError($code){

/* the parsed errors from the yml file */

    return $this->error[$code];

}

}

The yml file should be something like this

600:
    type: 'Internal Error'
    message: 'An internal error occurred'
    code: 600
```

Cache the parsed yml if it gets to big